# Null/empty 'getElementsByTagName' in my XML file

Tags: javascript, html, hta

My issue is when I make a call for a 'childNode' in my XML file. Everything works fine if there is information between the tags. If it is 'null' or empty, then my script errors out and doesn't continue processing. How do I get my script to ignore the 'null' childNode and continue running? I'm wanting to ignore the null reference and continue processing my XML file because some fields will be empty.

I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to get property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference.
```

--- HTML/HTA File - Works in IE 11 or as an .hta file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> -->
<!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"> -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>:: Races  ::</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION
     SCROLL="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     SYSMENU="yes"
     BORDER="dialog"
     ICON="ms-icon-144x144.png"
>

<!-- *** SETS HTA's WINDOW SIZE *** -->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
    Sub Window_onLoad

        window.resizeTo 1600,700

    End Sub 
</SCRIPT>
<!-- END SETS HTA's WINDOW SIZE *** -->

</head>
<body onload="LoadXML();">

<!-- *** XML - WRITE TO LOCAL FILE SCRIPT - XML *** -->
<script type ="text/javascript">
function WriteToFileXML()
{
  try 
  {
    var WshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    var userName = WshNetwork.UserName;
    var fso, s;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    if(fso.FileExists("M:/Races/test.xml")){
        s = fso.OpenTextFile("M:/Races/test.xml", 2, true);
        } else {
        s = fso.CreateTextFile("M:/Races/test.xml", true);
        }

    var one_seq=document.getElementById("OneSeqCheckbox").checked;
    var one_race_field=document.getElementById("OneRaceField").value;
    var one_county_selected=document.getElementById("OneCountySelected").value;

    var two_seq=document.getElementById("TwoSeqCheckbox").checked;
    var two_race_field=document.getElementById("TwoRaceField").value;
    var two_county_selected=document.getElementById("TwoCountySelected").value;

    var three_seq=document.getElementById("ThreeSeqCheckbox").checked;
    var three_race_field=document.getElementById("ThreeRaceField").value;
    var three_county_selected=document.getElementById("ThreeCountySelected").value;

s.writeline("\<\?xml version\=\"1\.0\" encoding\=\"UTF\-8\" standalone\=\"yes\"\?\>");
s.writeline("\<Races\_data xmlns\:xsi\=\"http\:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2001\/XMLSchema\-instance\"\>");

    if (one_seq==false)
        {
        s.writeline("");
        }
        else
            {
            s.writeline("   \<record\>");
            s.writeline("       \<Race\_Name\>" + one_race_field + "\<\/Race\_Name\>");
            s.writeline("       \<County\_Selected\>" + one_county_selected + "\<\/County\_Selected\>");
            s.writeline("   \<\/record\>");
            }
    if (two_seq==false)
        {
        s.writeline("");
        }
        else
            {
            s.writeline("   \<record\>");
            s.writeline("       \<Race\_Name\>" + two_race_field + "\<\/Race\_Name\>");
            s.writeline("       \<County\_Selected\>" + two_county_selected + "\<\/County\_Selected\>");
            s.writeline("   \<\/record\>");
            }
    if (three_seq==false)
        {
        s.writeline("");
        }
        else
            {
            s.writeline("   \<record\>");
            s.writeline("       \<Race\_Name\>" + three_race_field + "\<\/Race\_Name\>");
            s.writeline("       \<County\_Selected\>" + three_county_selected + "\<\/County\_Selected\>");
            s.writeline("   \<\/record\>");
            }
s.writeline("\<\/Races\_data\>");
    s.Close();
  } 
  catch(err)
  {
   var strErr = 'Error:';
   strErr += '\nNumber:' + err.number;
   strErr += '\nDescription:' + err.description;
   document.write(strErr);
  }
}
</script>
<!-- *** XML - END WRITE TO LOCAL FILE SCRIPT - XML *** -->

<h1>Races</h1>
<form id="myForm" onkeypress="return (event.keyCode !== 38);" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" autocomplete=off>
<div style="width:1300px;height:485px;overflow:auto;">
    <input name="OneRaceField" type="text" id="OneRaceField" size="30" /></td>
    <select name="OneCountySelected" id="OneCountySelected">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Mars County">Mars County</option>
        <option value="Jupiter County">Jupiter County</option>
    </select>
    <input name="TwoRaceField" type="text" id="TwoRaceField" size="30" /></td>
    <select name="TwoCountySelected" id="TwoCountySelected">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Mars County">Mars County</option>
        <option value="Jupiter County">Jupiter County</option>
    </select>
    <input name="ThreeRaceField" type="text" id="ThreeRaceField" size="30" /></td>
    <select name="ThreeCountySelected" id="ThreeCountySelected">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Mars County">Mars County</option>
        <option value="Jupiter County">Jupiter County</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div style="width: 150px; height: 200px; position:absolute; left: 1350px; top: 135px;">
<input style="width: 150px; height: 200px;" name="write_to_file" type="button" id="write_to_file" onClick="Validate(); WriteToFileXML(); RunExe();" value="Save Changes" />
<img src="please_wait.jpg" id="loading_image" name="loading_image" style="display:none" />
</div>
<div style="width: 150px; height: 200px; position:absolute; left: 1350px; top: 367px;">
<input style="width: 150px; height: 200px;" name="Reset_Form" type="button" id="Reset_Form" onClick="resetForm(); WriteToFileXML(); RunExe();" value="Reset Form" />
</div>
<!-- <div style="width: 150px; height: 200px; position:absolute; left: 693px; top: 367px;">
<input style="width: 150px; height: 200px;" name="upload_to_website" type="button" id="upload_to_website" onClick="RunExe();" value="Upload to Website" />
</div> -->
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadXML()
{
    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  

        //if(fso.fileExists("M:/Races/test.xml"))
        {       
        xmlDoc.load("M:/Races/test.xml");

            document.getElementById("OneRaceField").innerText =
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Race_Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;            
            document.getElementById("OneCountySelected").value =

            document.getElementById("TwoRaceField").innerText =
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Race_Name")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;            
            document.getElementById("TwoCountySelected").value =

            document.getElementById("ThreeRaceField").innerText =
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Race_Name")[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;            
            document.getElementById("ThreeCountySelected").value =
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("County_Selected")[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;      
        }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

--- test.xml - File Works fine

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Races_data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <record>
            <Race_Name>Mayor 1</Race_Name>
            <County_Selected>Mars County</County_Selected>
        </record>
        <record>
            <Race_Name>Mayor 2</Race_Name>
            <County_Selected>Jupiter County</County_Selected>
        </record>
        <record>
            <Race_Name>Mayor 3</Race_Name>
            <County_Selected>Mars County</County_Selected>
        </record>
</Races_data>
```

--- test.xml - Script stops/errors out because of missing information here:

```
<Race_Name></Race_Name>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Races_data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <record>
            <Race_Name>Mayor 1</Race_Name>
            <County_Selected>Mars County</County_Selected>
        </record>
        <record>
            <Race_Name></Race_Name>
            <County_Selected>Jupiter County</County_Selected>
        </record>
        <record>
            <Race_Name>Mayor 3</Race_Name>
            <County_Selected>Mars County</County_Selected>
        </record>
</Races_data>
```

Comment: well, I guess it's an error without a message? or do you think that error messages are useless? Or do you prefer that we look for this error by ourselves for the pleasure of complicating things?

Comment: When its an .hta, the error I get is: Unable to get property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference. When I open it as an HTML, I don't get an error. It just stops processing at <Race_Name></Race_Name> because it is empty.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear on my initial request. I'll update the original post to reflect my question. I'm wanting to ignore the null reference and continue processing my XML file because some fields will be empty.

Comment: been ages since I used loadXML, but it is not a url.....it should be the xml string

Comment: ActiveXObject is obsolete, did you use IE5 on Windows 2000?  why don't you use ajax request ?

Comment: This works in IE 11. Its also an .html file. I know HTML and HTML5 really well. Just a small amount of Javascript. I wouldn't know where to begin setting up an ajax request.

Comment: How is the html part for this ? did you create new html node ?

Comment: I added my HTML file to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

For  ajax you have to do something like that :

```
var my_url = 'M:/Races/test.xml';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (4 === this.readyState) {  /* DONE */
    if (200 === this.status) {  /* LOADING */
      fctCallBack(this);
    }
    else {
      console.warn("Error %d loading %s !", this.status, my_url);
    }
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();



function fctCallBack(xml) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

  xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('record').forEach(
    function (record) {
      console.log( 'Race_Name =' , record.querySelector('Race_Name').value )
      console.log( 'County_Selected =' , record.querySelector('County_Selected').value )
    }   
  )

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. I will try to implement it. I did rewrite my question and included the full .html file as an example.